# Objects in group make the entire group move

Tags: shortcut

When I try to move or rotate an object in a group, it also moves the rest of the group.

I see something at the bottom of the screen when I try to rotate it that says:

`Rot: 0.00 (Smooth) Proportional size: 1.00`

I must have accidentally hit a key that toggled this action. What key is it and what mode did it put me in?

I tried restarting Blender and reopening it but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Could you share the blend file. You can follow this link to know how.. https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: Proportional size is when you enable it ("O" key). But it would not affect the parent.

Comment: I hit the O key and it fixed the problem. Post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting the O key (thank you, @LeoNas) fixed the problem for me. If anyone knows why, please edit this answer.